# Retrieving collections from a database

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

I have two collections that I want to retrieve from the database and associate with each other. My solution works, however I know it isn't the most elegant one. Do you have any suggestions on how to improve the algorithm?

Classes:

```
 public class JobAnnouncement : IDbEntity
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public JobAnnouncementPosition Position { get; set; }
    public int PositionId { get; set; }
    public DateTime From { get; set; }
    public DateTime To { get; set; }
    public bool IsDeleted { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string PositionNameAdvertised { get; set; }
    public int? PortalId { get; set; }
    public JobAnnouncementPortal Portal { get; set; }
    public string OtherPortal { get; set; }
    public int? UserId { get; set; }
    public PragisUser User { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public DateTime From { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public DateTime To { get; set; }
    public int ReceivedCvCount { get; set; }
    public int InterviewedCount { get; set; }
    public int RecruitedCandidatesCount { get; set; }
    public string Comment { get; set; }
}
public class JobAnnouncementPosition
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public ICollection<JobAnnouncement> JobAnnouncements { get; set; }
     public ICollection<JobAnnouncementDocumentInfo> DocumentsInfo { get; set; }
    public PragisUserType PragisUserType {get;set;}
    [Range(1, int.MaxValue)]
    public int? TeamId { get; set; }
    public Team Team { get; set; }

    [Range(1, int.MaxValue)]
    public int? TechnologyId { get; set; }
    public JobAnnouncementTechnology Technology { get; set; }
    public string OtherTechnology { get; set; }

    [Range(1, int.MaxValue)]
    public int? LevelId { get; set; }
    public JobAnnouncementLevel Level { get; set; }
    public bool IsDeleted { get; set; }
     [NotMapped]
    public int JobAnnouncementsCount
    {
        get
        {
            return JobAnnouncements != null ? JobAnnouncements.Count : 0;
        }
    }
    }
```

Repository returning all positions that are not deleted with all associated announcements that are not deleted. I was not able to return all data on one database call as the condition of `IsDelted` for child entity announcements was not checked and I always got all announcements back, no matter if they were or weren't deleted.

I made two calls and then iterated over them assigning announcements to positions again:

```
 public IEnumerable<JobAnnouncementPosition> GetForListActive()
    {
        var announcements = _context.JobAnnouncements
            .Include(a => a.Portal)
            .Where(a => a.To.Day >= DateTime.Now.Day)
            .Where(a => a.IsDeleted == false)
            .ToList();

        var positions = _context.JobAnnouncementPositions
            .Include(a => a.Team)
            .Include(a => a.Level)
            .Include(a => a.Technology)
            .Include("DocumentsInfo.Document")
            .Where(p => p.IsDeleted == false)
            .ToList();

        foreach (var announcement in announcements)
        {
            foreach (var position in positions)
            {
                if (announcement.PositionId == position.Id)
                {
                    position.JobAnnouncements.Add(announcement);
                }
            }
        }

        var result = new List<JobAnnouncementPosition>();
        for (var i = 0; i < positions.Count; i++)
        {
            if (positions[i].JobAnnouncements != null)
            {
                result.Add(positions[i]);
            }
        }


        return result;

    }
```

Comment: It looks like you're basically performing an inner join - have you looked at [LINQ join operations](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt693045.aspx)?  You might even be able to perform the join before your `.ToList` calls to have the join execute on the database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two comments -

- Entity Framework already does what you do in the first loop. If you load entities into a context, for example by querying them, EF populates navigation properties by a process called *relationship fixup*.

  So if you do ...

  ```
  var announcements = _context.JobAnnouncements
      .Include(a => a.Portal)
      .Where(a => a.To.Day >= DateTime.Now.Day)
      .Where(a => a.IsDeleted == false)
      .ToList();

  var positions = _context.JobAnnouncementPositions
      .Include(a => a.Team)
      .Include(a => a.Level)
      .Include(a => a.Technology)
      .Include(a => a.DocumentsInfo.Select(d => d.Document))
      .Where(p => p.IsDeleted == false)
      .ToList();
  ```

  ... You'll notice that both `JobAnnouncement.JobAnnouncementPosition` and `JobAnnouncementPosition.JobAnnouncements` are populated as far as their entities are available.
- The second loop isn't necessary. You can return `positions`. It won't contain `null` objects.

That would leave you with the two queries and a return statement.

But there's more.

As you say, if you use `Include`, you get all data, including deleted items. It's because of this annoying inability of EF to filter `Include`s why such elaborate workarounds are necessary. But there is a third-party library that makes this a lot easier: [EntityFramework.DynamicFilters](https://github.com/jcachat/EntityFramework.DynamicFilters).

This library offers a simple API to define global filters that can be switched on and off. In you case it could look like:

```
modelBuilder.Filter("ActiveJobAnnouncements",
                        (JobAnnouncement a) => !a.IsDeleted);
modelBuilder.Filter("ActiveJobAnnouncementPositions",
                        (JobAnnouncementPositions p) => !p.IsDeleted);
```

Having these filters added to the model builder in `OnModelCreating`, you'll see that *whenever* you query any of these entities, the filter `!IsDeleted` will be part of the SQL query. Also when using `Include`s. If you want deleted items as well, just disable the filters in a context instance:

```
context.DisableFilter("ActiveJobAnnouncements");
context.DisableFilter("ActiveJobAnnouncementPositions");
```

I think this library is a gem.

One more thing: I my opinion, repositories, *if* you decide to use them, should be generic repositories. That means, for each entity class they do exactly the same thing. Your `GetForListActive()` method doesn't belong in a repository, rather in a service (that uses repositories).